# Spring @Autowire instance variable without xml config

Tags: spring, autowired

I am trying to autowire **java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap** to enforce a singleton implementation without using any spring-config.xml file. I'm fairly certain there is a way to do this via some spring annotation directly at the Java side of things, is this possible?

```
 @Component
 public class MyClass{

    //Some annotation goes here?   
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> myMap;
 }
```

Comment: Could you just make it a final instance variable of MyClass and assign it with a constructor?  For example, I build my ServiceImpls with final instantiations of the associated Repository.  I'm not sure you can accomplish this without config though.  Is there an opportunity for configuration classes?

Answer (score 0):

Actualy, you can not inject MAP.
But you can wrap your map in another class then inject it.

```
@Component
Public class MapWrapper {
    public Map<String, String> map = newConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
```

}

```
...
@Inject
private MapWrapper wrapper;
...
```